# How to create a new VM and use an existing DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

I'm having trouble creating a new VM on azure and applying an existing DNS to it.

is there an option somewhere in the azure portal ?

Regards,

Avishai.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to apply DNS servers to a VM:
1. Set the DNS servers at the vnet level (available in the portal)
2. Set the DNS servers at the cloud-service level (not available in the portal but is availably in Powershell as DnsSettings parameter to [New-AzureVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495254.aspx)).

Hth,
Gareth